# Multiple Column Plots in ggplot2 that are nearly identical

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I have a .tsv file that looks like this

```
MODEL           CA_RMSD BB_RMSD ALL_ATOM s1      s2     s3   
101_res_input   2.89    2.89    3.17    -84.37  -46.77  0.81   
102_res_input   3.29    3.29    3.52    -85.21  -50.49  1.04
103_res_input   3.74    3.73    3.98    -90.93  -48.18  1.65
104_res_input   3.09    3.07    3.34    -92.16  -49.63  1.03
105_res_input   3.44    3.43    3.69    -89.92  -49.81  1.08
```

What I would like is one graph that has CA_RMSD vs s1, then another one with CA_RMSD vs s2, and another with CA_RMSD vs s3 and so on. Scatter plot would probably work the best I imagine. I'm new to ggplot2, but it almost seems like facetting is what I want to use as I would like all the plots on the same image, but for each plot, the y-axis will need to be in a different scale.

For each plot can I get a linear regression on the scale telling me which sets of data correlate the best? There has to be some function i'm missing to do this.

J

Comment: You have basically done nothing after you've got this data? If not, then why not post what you've got so far?

Comment: Yes, I have used qplot to plot each one individually, but then used mutliplot to put them all on the same page. It's wildly inefficient and unscriptable.

Comment: Then, it is better to post your code up until what you've done and then ask for what you couldn't. Else, you're going to get down voted for lack of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var = "CA_RMSD", measure.var = c("X.s1", "s2", "s3"))
p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x = CA_RMSD, y = value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
    facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow=1, scales="free")
cors <- ddply(df.m, .(variable), summarise, cor = round(cor(CA_RMSD, value), 2))
p + geom_text(data=cors, aes(label=paste("r=", cor, sep=""), 
                   x=c(3,3,3), y=c(-75, -50, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I promise I will look into each function you have described so we don't have to see this issue again :)